# How can I do Mini-Template System in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, template-engine

First of all, I want to describe What mean with Mini-Template System.For example; I have one html file that uploaded by user.There are many html/css codes.I need to determine some tags like html.If user write **{posts} {/posts}** to html.System should runn listPosts method.I know, I should do this with regex.But I dont have any idea how can I read html file? Should I read this file with Java's File Class? or Are there anything like file_get_contents() method in php? Also, If I use Java's File Class how can I read all html tags in groups?
Thank you for helping
Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to use HtmlCleaner: 
http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/

It can be very helpful when you can get specific html tags...